# Regular expression using string.matches always returning false though i am expecting true

Tags: java

I am trying to find the whether all the case-based characters in the string following the non based-characters. i.e Non case-based characters are in upper case and all other case based characters are in lower case

> example: What Is Your Test

Regular expression which i have defined is : `\b[A-Z]`

```
String alphaCheck="What Is Your Test";
System.out.println(alphaCheck.matches("\b[A-Z]"));
```

Comment: There is more than one word boundary, and your `String` you want to compare it to has to EXACTLY match the expression. I think you´re better of using a `Matcher` and it´s `find` functionality. Otherwise your expression has to be `".*\b[A-Z].*"` in order for the expression to match the rest of your `String`

Comment: I don't quite understand your question

Comment: Here is my code System.out.println(alphaCheck.matches("\b[A-Z]"));

Comment: @TheLostMind i think he wants to check if each words starts with an uppercase char.

Comment: Yeah thats right. I want to check that the each wort start with an uppercase char. @TheLostMind

Answer (score 1):

`([A-Z][a-z]+(\\s+|$))+` will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "What Is Your Test";
    System.out.println(s.matches("([A-Z][a-z]+(\\s+|$))+"));

    String s2 = "What is";
    System.out.println(s2.matches("([A-Z][a-z]+(\\s+|$))+"));
}
```

O/P :

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

As another option you could use the negative way, and check if there is any not fitting your criteria:

```
String alphaCheck="What Is Your Test";
System.out.println(!alphaCheck.matches(".*\\b[a-z]+.*"));
alphaCheck="What Is Your test";
System.out.println(!alphaCheck.matches(".*\\b[a-z]+.*"));
alphaCheck="what Is Your Test";
System.out.println(!alphaCheck.matches(".*\\b[a-z]+.*"));
```

O/P:

```
true
false
false
```

You just have to revert the `String#matches` return to represent if it´s correct or not.